# Why doesn't my object return the date?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to test out objects in javascript. Why doesn't my s object return the date?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function test() {
        var date = new Date(); 
        return date.getMilliseconds();            
    }

    var s = new test();
    console.log(s);

</script>
```

Comment: Does it return the milliseconds?

Comment: it says it just returns test.  Console.log typeof says it's an object.

Comment: What is happening when I have new keyword and if i remove it? It works without  new test()

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

```
var s = new test();
```

Should be

```
var s = test();
```

The `new` keyword is used to create a new object, and in this case a constructor can only return a non-primitive object.  Since you just want to return milliseconds, call `test()` without `new`

Comment: So s becomes a new object. What happens to my return Date.getMilliseconds()? does it get discarded?

Comment: yes, s becomes a new instance of test, and the return value is ignored because it is a primitive type.  if test() returned this "return {miliseconds: date.getMilliseconds()}; " then s=new test() would be an object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

If you want to create an instance of test()

```
var test = (function () {
    function test() {
        this.date = new Date();
    }
    test.prototype.getMilliseconds = function () {
        return this.date.getMilliseconds();
    };
    return test;
})();

var s = new test().getMilliseconds();
console.log(s);
```